# How do I "pause" Server Sent Events?

Tags: server-sent-events, pausing-execution

How I pause a Server Sent Event connection? Is it even possible, or do I have to close the SSE and then reopen it and assign all of the event handlers again?

For example I would like to do (this is all theoretical, I do not know the pause/restart function names):

```
var source = new EventSource(url);

source.addEventListener("something", somefunction, false);
source.addEventListener("somethingElse", somefunction2, false);

//...some code

source.pause();


//...some code

source.restart();
```

Comment: This project may serve as inspiration: [wikimedia-streams](https://github.com/ChlodAlejandro/wikimedia-streams) (main code is [here](https://github.com/ChlodAlejandro/wikimedia-streams/blob/master/src/index.ts)).

Comment: The project linked above also has features "autoreconnect on lost connection" and ability to choose the starting point in the stream, by supplying a header "Last-Event-ID". Though, it requires this [EventSource implementation](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) instead of the browser native implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what technically needs to happen but you can abstract it away. Note: This one only connects after you do `.connect()`

```
function EventSource2(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.es = null;
    this.listeners = {};
}

EventSource2.prototype = {
    constructor: EventSource2,
    
    
    connect: function() {
        this.es = new EventSource(this.url);
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    
    disconnect: function() {
        this.es.close();
        this.es = null;
    },
    
    bindEvents: function() {
        for ( var type in this.listeners ) {
            var evs = this.listeners[type];
            for( var i = 0; i < evs.length; ++i ) {
                this.es.addEventListener( type, evs[i], false );
            }
        }
    },
    
    addEventListener: function( type, fn ) {
        if( !this.listeners[type] ) {
            this.listeners[type] = [];
        }
        
        this.listeners[type].push( fn );
        if( this.es ) {
            this.bindEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var source = new EventSource2(url);

source.addEventListener("something", somefunction, false);
source.addEventListener("somethingElse", somefunction2, false);

source.connect();

source.disconnect();

source.connect();
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but it seemed _hacky_

Comment: Nothing *hacky* about it, this is exactly why abstractions over low level constructs exist.

Comment: There's a little typo in function bindEvents. The L should be uppercase in this.es.addEventListener().

Comment: @Naftali Why the rollback?

Comment: @GrasDouble well... I rolled back bc I am not sure why code in the answer from 10 years ago was changed!

Comment: Wow, I didn't think EventSource were more than 10 years old! (and still not supported by IE…) Please note my changes consist only of fixing obvious mistakes. For example, revision 3 fixes unused arguments for snippet's `addEventListener` (which has the same name as browser's `Element.addEventListener`).